# The newsletter is suddenly calling questions with low votes, low views and no answers "top new questions this week"

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

So I just received my Ask Ubuntu newsletter and upon opening it up I was disappointed to see what it now considers "top questions" for the week all have <1 vote, low views (~<50) and sometimes even no answers (e.g. [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542795/popup-ad-virus-on-both-chrome-and-firefox?newsletter=1&nlcode=115466|74c4), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542788/error-while-upgrading-kubuntu-14-04-to-14-10?newsletter=1&nlcode=115466|74c4), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542721/how-to-recover-ubuntu-from-bad-gnome-remove?newsletter=1&nlcode=115466|74c4)). Not only can these hardly be called "top" questions, but they are a far cry from what the section usually contains.

I looked at last week's email and it had the normal "real" top questions with lots of votes, views, answers, etc. (e.g. [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537196/how-do-i-patch-workaround-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566?newsletter=1&nlcode=115466|74c4), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537586/why-i-can-find-main-o-but-cannot-o?newsletter=1&nlcode=115466|74c4), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539395/deleting-input-back-to-the-last-forward-slash?newsletter=1&nlcode=115466|74c4)) so I am calling this a bug because this isn't what used to come in that section of the email and I don't think it is what was meant to be sent.

Comment: Maybe it's trying to predict the future... ?

Comment: Remember "upside-down day" from primary school?  It's kind of like that.

Comment: Maybe they want to prevent [tumbleweed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed)s?

Comment: MSO post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275537/i-just-received-my-stack-overflow-weekly-newsletter-and-the-top-new-questions

Comment: We're looking into this.

Comment: This should be fixed as per: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275551/74757

Comment: @Anna --^ wanna mark this as completed?